# Stanford Dependency Parser using NLTK on Python very Slow

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

```
path_to_jar = path + 'stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser.jar'
path_to_models_jar = path + 'stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser-3.6.0-models.jar'
sentence='This is a nice phone 4 me'

print 'Loading module'
start= time.time()
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)
print time.time()-start

start=time.time()
result = dependency_parser.raw_parse((sentence))
print result
print time.time()-start
```

I've been working on Dependency Parsing using Stanford and NLTK. The probelm I face is the execution time. Here is the output for the above code

```
Loading module
0.0047550201416
<listiterator object at 0x10bbcbb10>
3.65611600876
```

It takes approximately 4 seconds per sentence/text. In java, using static variables to load module, its super fast. Any suggestions? At this rate it will take me 100 hours to train provided no error occurs!

Comment: You're conflating parser load time with parsing time. Try using `raw_parse_sents` when parsing multiple sentences.

Comment: That helped, thank-you! Have you come across Assertion Errors while execution. One of my datasets got caught, and none of the solution like decoding signed-utf-8 works.